# Is Mary Ann Schinfield a real person?

Tags: psychics, nasa

One day, while bouncing around some alternate history and conspiracy theory videos I came across a reference to a man named **Drunvalo Melchizedek**. I was curious about some of his work and decided to check out one of his books *[The Ancient Secret of the Flower of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1891824171)*. In the very first chapter I started questioning some of the claims about his research and decided to start fact checking, and hit a dead end on my first query (...not a huge surprise for a book in the *New Age* section).

In his book he states that there was a blind woman named "**Mary Ann Schinfield**" that was studied by NASA and had some extraordinary psychic-like abilities.

Here is an excerpt from another of his books, [Living In The Heart](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52386014/5/A-Blind-Woman-Can-See):

> I met Mary Ann Schinfield, an outstandingly unusual woman. (I mentioned her briefly in the first volume of The Ancient Secret of the Flower of Life.) Mary Ann was completely blind and technically had no eyes, could see absolutely nothing. However, she was able to perform normal everyday tasks — she could even read a book and watch television without any outside assistance. NASA scientists performed extensive tests to determine how she was able to "see." They asked her what she was seeing inside her head while she was sitting in a room, and she—as she related to me later—told them that she was moving through space and was continuously watching what was going on in the solar system. Even more interesting was that she said she was restricted to this solar system and couldn't leave. Of course, NASA didn't believe that she was "moving through space," and so they made up a test to see whether she was telling the truth. They asked her to move alongside one of their satellites and give them some kind of a reading from it, a serial number or something. I'm not sure what it was, but she did it precisely, and from that moment on, Mary Ann belonged to NASA. They have never let her go and continue to use her for their own purposes.

However I cannot find a single shred of evidence or information about this woman. All my searches lead me back to Drunvalo Melchizedek. Does anyone have any information on this? Is it completely bogus?

Comment: I like the bit later on where he speculates she is an alien, and a sample of her DNA would show her as "outside of Earth's biological history". Her *DNA*?

Comment: Presumably you turn to the book's extensive scholarly bibliography and ... What's that you say? No bibliography? Oh.

Comment: Why, of all agencies, would The National **Aeronautics and Space** Administration be the one interested in studying a psychic?

Comment: Interesting video of Melchizedek talking about her [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuD8S7I-K_k&list=PLA5DD99AC8082B84B).  Nothing that can be verified, but he talks about an "experience" where he sees as Mary Ann does.  He certainly seems to *believe* in what he wrote, but that doesn't say anything about it's veracity.

Comment: Researching this question led to some amusing other claims in the book.  Apparently, [underwater births with dolphin midwives result in babies with an IQ of at least 150](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E0FEcoK0ds4C&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=%22underwater+birthing+and+dolphin+midwives%22&source=bl&ots=7eZYQKwaiD&sig=6OzEHCIaRxFJXfWFQNU8XuT6PYc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZxomTr_LTAhXEIMAKHcjUCzwQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22underwater%20birthing%20and%20dolphin%20midwives%22&f=false)…

Comment: @gerrit - above-water births with dolphin midwives?  Only 135, sadly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is completely bogus.

Although absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, her name has [no results on the NASA website](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Mary+Ann+Schinfield&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wtkZWYugFM_38AeA1LPoAQ#channel=fs&q=%22Mary+Ann+Schinfield%22+site:nasa.gov) (only Mary Ann Esfandiari does; unrelated).

Taking another look at the book you mention, [it is full of claims that are highly implausible](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OAyPTi-9vyoC&pg=PP46&lpg=PP46&dq=%22Mary+Ann+Schinfield%22&source=bl&ots=Jf8_h2a55a&sig=4QZPSFXLnqA1fQ7Klq509msIv88&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiooLqmq_LTAhVBJsAKHbZvAcA4ChDoAQgyMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mary%20Ann%20Schinfield%22&f=false) (to put it mildly):

[image: excerpt from book]

There is no evidence for these extraordinary claims.  Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  In particular, flying alongside a satellite does not mean one can read off their instruments; satellites do not have dials and instruments to be read by a person next to the satellite, so the “evidence” provided does not make sense.

There are [rational explanations for out-of-body experiences](http://www.baltimoresun.com/bs-mtblog-2007-12-outofbody_experiences_not_so_o-story.html), and can in some cases be actively induced, according to [a publication in the New England Journal of Medicine](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa070010#t=article):

> It has been suggested that out-of-body experiences are the result of a transient failure to integrate the visual, tactile, proprioceptive, and vestibular information that converges at the temporoparietal junction, especially on the right side of the brain. Out-of-body experiences have attracted the most interest when reported by people who have had near-death experiences, but they have also been reported to occur spontaneously in patients with epilepsy or migraine and have been induced by electrical stimulation of the temporoparietal junction on the right side in patients with epilepsy.

[References within that article](http://www.nejm.org/doi/ref/10.1056/NEJMoa070010#t=references) contain many more medical explanations for perceived out-of-body experiences.

Whether there has been a person called Mary Ann Schinfield is difficult to determine.  However, the claims *about* this person are incredibly unlikely to be true.

Comment: "known to be impossible" seems... overly certain for a skeptic's answer without supporting evidence - especially about something that's largely not disprovable.  Its highly implausible, and its support is weak enough to be near-laughable, but "known to be impossible" seems like the sort of phrase that ought to be throwing caution flags.

Comment: @BenBarden True.  I have adapted my choice of words.

Comment: I'd just like to note that completely ordinary, non psychic blind people have been known to navigate without assistance (even without a walking stick). They use echolocation (no, seriously, google "human echolocation" - there's even a school that teaches the skill). In one famous case the boy can even ride a bicycle on the streets in a major city (New York if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: What I find particularly piquant? Is that normally when you search for any name, PeopleFinder and other associated sites come up with information on the name. For this woman's name, even the name in general, NONE of that comes up. Not one search result from any people finder sites. Now THATS odd.